# Having trouble with putting a transparent image as a texture over a solid material

Tags: cinema-4d

Basically I am trying to overlay an image with a transparent background as a texture over a solid material.  I have googled it so many times but I haven't found any answers.  Also I am unable to use octane render since i am on mac so please don't post an answer that involves it.

Answer (score 1):

Create two different materials:

1. solid color or texture
2. your .png image, be sure to put it in `alpha` tab as texture

Now you can add both textures to your object. Remember to put .png texture on the right to the solid color one. You can also change color of .png texture in `color` tab.

[image]